# How to provide C++ version when extending python

Tags: python, c++, distutils

I want to make c++ code callable from python.

https://docs.python.org/3/extending/ explains how to do this, but does not mention how to specify c++ version.

By default distutils calls g++ with a bunch of arguments, however does not provide the version argument.
Example of setup.py:

```py
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

MOD = "ext"

module = Extension("Hello", sources = ["hello.cpp"])

setup(
    name="PackageName",
    version="0.01",
    description="desc",
    ext_modules = [module]
)
```

I'm using linux, if that matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass compiler arguments as `extra_compile_args` so for example

```
module = Extension(
  "Hello",
  sources = ["hello.cpp"],
  extra_compile_args = ["-std=c++20"]
)
```

Comment: "/std:c++20" in my case